# Failing to svnsync onto an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, svn, amazon-ec2, svnsync

I am trying to mirror an SVN repository to an EC2 instance using the command

```
svnsync init svn+ssh://ec2-user@[IP of EC2 instance]/[mirror repo location] file://[local repo location]
```

but am getting the following error

> svnsync: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://ec2-user@[IP of EC2 instance]/[mirror repo location]

I have loaded the .pem private key file using ssh-add, but I don't think it is being used to grant access to the repo on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Until you verify that you can simply `ssh ec2-user@[IP of EC2 instance]` without specifying the private key, the `svn+ssh` command definitely will not work, so troubleshoot that, first.

Comment: I can ssh into the EC2 instance without any problems. (without specifying the key)